# nav-bar item did not work as expected although copied like the design from bulma's website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulma

I am working with rails and here is my problem.

I copied the "Transparent navbar" example from this link

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/

I copied the code, and added this code to the file application.html.erb of my code,
and here is what I got, as you can see in this picture

[image: My problem]

Here is the design

[image: The design]

As you can see, the design is very different with my page. I want my page to be like the design.

Here is my code.

https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/freelancer

I am setting rails -v 7.0.4 and ruby -v 3.1.2

Could you please give me some advices for this problem ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `Bulma` library is not loaded into your layout, you should install it first in able to be order to use their styles.

You can do it via a CDN or adding the package to your bundle (see full docs: https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start). Maybe the simplest way to start out, is to use the CDN approach:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.4/css/bulma.min.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But sorry because I still do not how to add the package to my bundle, it is the Gemfile or the config file ? So maybe the easier way is run the code "npm install bulma" ?

Comment: Just add the CDN link in your layout. The package.json approach needs a Node.js runtime, so it's a bit complicated.

Comment: thanks, but to find the package.json file is very difficult, so I tried the easier way is to ran this command "yarn add bulma" and it worked, by the way thank you very much for your comment